# passing pointer to strcat does not update the string

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop, strcat

I'm writing my own version of `strcat` in C following K&R. This is my code:

```
#define MAXVALUE 1000

void concat(char *s, char *t)
{
    while (*s++)
        ;
    while (*s++ = *t++)
        ;
}

/* test */
int main()
{
    char s1[MAXVALUE];
    char s2[] = "Jim!";
    s1[0] = 'H', s1[1] = 'i', s1[2] = ' ';
    s1[3] = '\0';
    concat(s1, s2);
    printf("%s\n", s1);
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is to copy `s2` into `s1` to obtain "Hi Jim!". I made sure that `s1` is large enough to contain both strings. However, when I run this, it outputs "Hi", so basically it does not update the string `s1`. I'm at a loss as to why: `s1` still points at `s1[0] = 'H'` and after running `concat` the `'\0'` in `s1[3]` should have been replaced and `s1` should be terminated with `'\0'` at `s1[7]`.

P.S. Note that as in K&R, my version of `strcat` does not match the standard library one. In particular, the return value is void.

Comment: Your first `while` advances past the null terminator. Use `while (*s) s++;` instead, so `*s` is the null character after the loop.

Comment: @Himanshu wouldn't that iterate twice?Once inside the while, and once in the brackets.I think it's somehow correct how he wrote it.First it iterates until the end of the `*s` then will concatenate at the end of the `*s` and `*t` and increment to the next element. The comment posted by @MOeehm is correct.

Comment: @MOehm Yes, you're right. Inserting `s--` between whiles solves the problem. Thanks for help, such a stupid mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the problem is, after reaching the terminating `NUL`, you're advancing the pointer `*s++`, so, it is included in the destination string, making the `printf()` to interpret as the end of string. As per the design rule of string concatination, you need to remove [or replace, or overwrite] the terminating `NUL` and add the second string.

To avoid the terminating `NUL` apperaing in the output string, do not increment the pointer when it reaches `NUL`, instead, start copying the next string from that particular location itself.

Check the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXVALUE 1000

void concat(char *s, char *t)
{
    while (*s)  s++;     //after NUL, do not increment, move on to copying
    while (*s++ = *t++)
        ;
}

/* test */
int main()
{
    char s1[MAXVALUE];
    char s2[] = "Jim!";
    s1[0] = 'H', s1[1] = 'i', s1[2] = ' ';
    s1[3] = '\0';
    concat(s1, s2);
    printf("%s\n", s1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```
void concat(char *s, char *t) 
{
       while (*s != '\0')
          s++; 
           while (*s++ = *t++)
                      ;   
}

/* test */
int main()
{
   char s1[MAXVALUE];
   char s2[] = "Jim!";
   s1[0] = 'H', s1[1] = 'i', s1[2] = ' ';
   s1[3] = '\0';
   concat(s1, s2);
   printf("%s\n", s1);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MOehm, I fixed the code by simply inserting `s--` to compensate for going past the null terminator:

```
void concat(char *s, char *t)
{
    while (*s++)
        ;
    s--;
    while (*s++ = *t++)
        ;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `while (*s)  s++;`?

Comment: no reason; just wanted to make only minimal corrections to my code. Either one would work.

Comment: The reason why I asked was that I think going one step too far and then stepping back is not so clean and elegant as omitting the extra step at the first place...